# How to get values from array using POST method

Tags: php, html

How to get value in another page using the POST method?

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" value = "1" name="jsq[1]" checked>1
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" value = "2" name="jsq[1]">2
</label></br>
<label>
    <input type="radio" value = "3" name="jsq[1]">3
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" value = "4" name="jsq[1]">4
</label></br>
<label>
    <input type="radio" value = "5" name="jsq[1]">5
</label>
```

I want to get value of `jsq[1]` in `myarr[1]`. How can I do that?

```
$myarr[1] = $_POST['jsq[1]'];
```

Comment: `$_POST['jsq'][1']` - all of your inputs have the same name so only 1 of the values will come through

Comment: Why using array on radio buttons ?

Comment: `$myarr[1] = $_POST['jsq'][1];` You might have found it yourself with a simple test by printing the content of $_POST. ;)

Comment: @FuzzyTree — They're radio buttons, you're only going to get one of them anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without going into the question why you're naming them jsq[1] an not just jsq...

you're almost there, but it should be

```
$myarr[1] = $_POST['jsq'][1];
```

It's by the way always a good idea to check this king of things using print_r($_POST); or var_dump($_POST);